# Use unicode 3.2 for computation of upper() and lower()

Tags: python, unicode

From what I understand, Python uses the most current Unicode Character Database (UCD) when computing `str.lower()` or `str.upper()`. Is it possible to compute it using UCD 3.2? The solution doesn't necessarily have to be Python-native, it could be a 3rd party dependency or even a non-python native software which I call from Python (but a native, fast-performance version is preferred).

The reason why I need this is because my software needs to apply Unicode normalization the same way as a legacy system does, which was released during Unicode 3.2 times.

Cheers!

Comment: Quick clarification: by "native", what do you mean? Stdlib? Pure-Python? Written in C?

Comment: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.1.3/ was released apr of 2002 ... UCD3.2 was march of 2002 ...

Comment: Good luck. Wont be easy. Here's the [official normalization test suite for unicode 3.2](https://www.unicode.org/Public/3.2-Update/NormalizationTest-3.2.0.txt). You can use it to validate correctness of whatever you find/implement. The simplest solution might be to just create an executable that uses python2.1.3 to perform the normalization. Alternatively copy&paste the unicode implementation from python2.1.3 in an extension module (with the correct changes to avoid clashes).

Comment: With native I mean stdlib or a C-program or C-lib. I should also clarify that my software is based on Python 3.6/3.7, which I'm unwilling to change. However, it might be a possible solution to use Python 2.1.3 (either as a 3rd party binary, or using its code as an ext. module).

Comment: If all else fails, you could always process the Unicode 3.2 [UnicodeData](https://unicode.org/Public/3.2-Update/UnicodeData-3.2.0.txt) and [SpecialCasing](https://unicode.org/Public/3.2-Update/SpecialCasing-3.2.0.txt) files yourself.

Comment: Actually, I'm thinking about sampling the behavior of the legacy system by brute-force and building a mapping table (simple Python dict). I have no guarantee that the legacy system (closed source) would behave the same way as any other 3.2-based implementation (regardless of whether I parse the Unicode files myself or use ancient Python source code).

Comment: There's also no guarantee that such a dict would work. Maybe the legacy system had support for locale-sensitive or context-sensitive case mappings. If you want to match the legacy system exactly, finding its source or decompiling its binary may be necessary.

Comment: There is `unicodedata.ucd_3_2_0` object that has the same methods as the entire `unicodedata` module, but uses the Unicode database version 3.2 instead, for applications that require this specific version of the Unicode database (such as IDNA). *New in Python version 2.5.*